# Using the 'ws' library on a specific request

Tags: node.js, websocket, ws

I would like to use the `ws` NPM package to write a websocket server.

However, the ways `ws` can be set up is more or less as follows:

1. Start a new Websocket server on its own port.
2. Use an existing `Server` object, listen to the `upgrade` event and hook in the Websocket server.

I would like to find a way to do neither of these things.

Instead, I would like to:

1. See if there was an `Upgrade: websocket` header.
2. Initialize `ws` just for that that specific client/socket and get a `Websocket` object for that connection.

I realize that by doing that, I lose the ability to broadcast to all connected users. But my goal basically is:

"Here's an incoming http request, please give me a Websocket for this"

I can't tell from the `ws` documentation if this is a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this can help, but there is the [express-ws library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ws) that allows you to add `ws` endpoints to a express app.

Comment: Hey this was very interesting, because they are trying to solve a very similar problem! Unfortunately, they also don't seem to handle this. They're also starting their own global instance of WebSocket.Server